# What would be the fastest way to implement Dominant Assurance Contracts (which depend on multisignature transactions) with Monero?

Tags: multisig, dominant-assurance

I think that dominant assurance contracts are a significantly overlooked or poorly explored idea for the entire cypherpunk and cryptocurrency community.

I'd like for all of us to do more exploration with it, but before that's possible there needs to be some implementation of it.  So, what's the quickest, cheapest way to get a script that allows for a dominant assurance contract to be executed using Monero?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assurance_contract#Dominant_assurance_contracts

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Dominant_Assurance_Contracts

https://mason.gmu.edu/~atabarro/PrivateProvision.pdf

Comment: Could you add some good link which describe what those are? It will help for anyone interested to look into it. Maybe [this?](https://mason.gmu.edu/~atabarro/PrivateProvision.pdf)

Comment: Thanks added links.  The bitcoin wiki is helpful in explaining how to do it in cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple built-in multisig option for now with Monero, we'll have to wait for RingCT and the multisig extension built on it.

So for now, probably there is no option to implement it at all.

Comment: I thought RingCT was recently added to Monero?

Comment: Yes, waiting HF for activation. But it's not coming together with multisig - it is a prerequisite to multisig, though. Multisig is the next thing on the todo list I suppose

Comment: Any ETA for multisignature?

Comment: @jollymort technically not. They are just waiting for multisig so they don't have to redo the work.